# TypeError: PySide.QtCore.QObject.connect(): not enough arguments

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qthread, qt-signals

I'm trying to emit a singal from a `QThread` to update the `progressBar`

```
class Signal(QtCore.QObject):
    this = QtCore.Signal(int)

class Load(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
            QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.onProgress = Signal()

    def run(self):
        '''
        '''
        stacks = []
        count = 100
        for i in range(count):
            # do something ... 
            self.onProgress.this.emit(count)
```

And how I call it in the MainWindow

```
    def __init__(self ... ):
            ...
            self.Thread = Load(self)
            self.Thread.onProgress.connect(self.onProgress)
            self.Thread.start()

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def onProgress(self, int):
        self.ui.progressBar.setValue(self.ui.progressBar.value() + (90/int))
```

but I always get this error

```
TypeError: PySide.QtCore.QObject.connect(): not enough arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting to `onProgress`, which is an instance of the `Signal` class (a misleading name in this context). You want to be connecting to the `onProgress.this`, which is the actual signal object:

```
self.Thread.onProgress.this.connect(self.onProgress)
```

Alternatively assign `onProgress` to the signal itself:

```
self.onProgress = Signal().this
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with the `this` name, but I don't think it will work.  Have you looked at [Signals and Slots in PySide](https://wiki.qt.io/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide)? It has quite a nice description.  I think you just need something like this:

```
class Load(QtCore.QThread):

    onProgress = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self):
        '''
        '''
        stacks = []
        count = 100
        for i in range(count):
            # do something ... 
            self.onProgress.emit(count)
```